# Net does not change weights during training, pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm implementing DDPG and got stuck training my two nets.

All in all I've got 4 nets called: actor, actor_target, critic and critic_target.
I'm training the actor and critic in the training loop and do soft updates for the other two nets with:

```
def update_weights(self, source, tau):
        for target, source in zip(self.parameters(), source.parameters()):
            target.data.copy_(tau * source.data + (1 - tau) * target.data)
```

My training loop looks like:

```
tensor_next_states = torch.tensor(next_states).view(-1, 1)
prediction_target = self.actor_target(tensor_next_states).data.numpy()
target_critic_output = self.critic_target(
    construct_tensor(next_states, prediction_target))
y = torch.tensor(rewards).view(-1,1) + \
    self.gamma * target_critic_output
output_critic = self.critic(
    torch.tensor(construct_tensor(states, actions), dtype=torch.float))

# compute loss and update critic
self.critic.zero_grad()
loss_critic = self.criterion_critic(y, output_critic)
loss_critic.backward()
self.critic_optim.step()

# compute loss and update actor
tensor_states = torch.tensor(states).view(-1, 1)
ouput_actor = self.actor(tensor_states).data.numpy()
self.actor.zero_grad()
loss_actor = (-1.) * \
             self.critic(construct_tensor(states, ouput_actor)).mean()
loss_actor.backward()
self.actor_optim.step()

# update target
self.actor_target.update_weights(self.actor, self.tau)
self.critic_target.update_weights(self.critic, self.tau)
```

using `SGD` as optimizer and `self.criterion_critic = F.mse_loss`.

`construct_tensor(a,b)` constructs a tensor like `[a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1], ...]`.

I've noticed, that the RMSE on the test set before and after training is the same.
So I debugged a lot and noticed in `update_weights` that the weights of the trained net and the target net are the same - so I concluded, that the training does not have any affect on the weights of the trained net.
I already checked that the computed losses are not zero but still a float, checked replacing the `zero_grad()` calls and moving the computed losses to `self`, which hadn't got any impact.

Does anyone already met this behavior and/or has any tips or know how to fix this?

**Update:** Full code:

```
import datetime
import random
from collections import namedtuple

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim


def combine_tensors(s, a):
    """
    Combines the two given tensors
    :param s: tensor1
    :param a: tensor2
    :return: combined tensor
    """
    target = []
    if not len(a[0].shape) == 0:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            target.append(torch.cat((s[i], a[i])).data.numpy())
    else:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            target.append(torch.cat((s[i], a[i].float().view(-1))) \
                          .data.numpy())
    return torch.tensor(target, device=device)


class actor(nn.Module):
    """
    Actor - gets a state (2-dim) and returns probabilities about which
    action to take (4 actions -> 4 outputs)
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(actor, self).__init__()

        # define net structure
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(2, 4)
        self.hidden_layer_1 = nn.Linear(4, 8)
        self.hidden_layer_2 = nn.Linear(8, 16)
        self.hidden_layer_3 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(32, 4)

        # initialize them
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.input_layer.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer_1.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer_2.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer_3.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.output_layer.weight)

        nn.init.constant_(self.input_layer.bias, 0.1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.hidden_layer_1.bias, 0.1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.hidden_layer_2.bias, 0.1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.hidden_layer_3.bias, 0.1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.output_layer.bias, 0.1)

    def forward(self, state):
        state = F.relu(self.input_layer(state))
        state = F.relu(self.hidden_layer_1(state))
        state = F.relu(self.hidden_layer_2(state))
        state = F.relu(self.hidden_layer_3(state))
        state = F.softmax(self.output_layer(state), dim=0)
        return state


class critic(nn.Module):
    """
    Critic - gets a state (2-dim) and an action and returns value
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(critic, self).__init__()
        # define net structure
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(3, 8)
        self.hidden_layer_1 = nn.Linear(8, 16)
        self.hidden_layer_2 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        self.hidden_layer_3 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(16, 1)

        # initialize them
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.input_layer.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer_1.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer_2.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer_3.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.output_layer.weight)

        nn.init.constant_(self.input_layer.bias, 0.1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.hidden_layer_1.bias, 0.1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.hidden_layer_2.bias, 0.1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.hidden_layer_3.bias, 0.1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.output_layer.bias, 0.1)

    def forward(self, state_, action_):
        state_ = combine_tensors(state_, action_)
        state_ = F.relu(self.input_layer(state_))
        state_ = F.relu(self.hidden_layer_1(state_))
        state_ = F.relu(self.hidden_layer_2(state_))
        state_ = F.relu(self.hidden_layer_3(state_))
        state_ = self.output_layer(state_)
        return state_


Transition = namedtuple('Transition',
                        ('state', 'action', 'next_state', 'reward'))


class ReplayMemory(object):
    """
    Memory
    """

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = []
        self.position = 0

    def push(self, *args):
        if len(self.memory) < self.capacity:
            self.memory.append(None)
        self.memory[self.position] = Transition(*args)
        self.position = (self.position + 1) % self.capacity

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)


def compute_action(actor_trainined, state, eps=0.1):
    """
    Computes an action given the actual policy, the state and an eps.
    Eps is resposible for the amount of exploring
    :param actor_trainined: actual policy
    :param state:
    :param eps: float in [0,1]
    :return:
    """
    denoise = random.random()

    if denoise > eps:
        action_probs = actor_trainined(state.float())
        return torch.argmax(action_probs).view(1).int()
    else:
        return torch.randint(0, 4, (1,)).view(1).int()


def compute_next_state(_action, _state):
    """
    Computes the next state given an action and a state
    :param _action:
    :param _state:
    :return:
    """
    state_ = _state.clone()
    if _action.item() == 0:
        state_[1] += 1
    elif _action.item() == 1:
        state_[1] -= 1
    elif _action.item() == 2:
        state_[0] -= 1
    elif _action.item() == 3:
        state_[0] += 1

    return state_


def update_weights(target, source, tau):
    """
    Soft-Update of weights
    :param target:
    :param source:
    :param tau:
    :return:
    """
    for target, source in zip(target.parameters(), source.parameters()):
        target.data.copy_(tau * source.data + (1 - tau) * target.data)


def update(transition__, replay_memory, batch_size_, gamma_):
    """
    Performs one update step
    :param transition__:
    :param replay_memory:
    :param batch_size_:
    :param gamma_:
    :return:
    """
    replay_memory.push(*transition__)

    if replay_memory.__len__() < batch_size_:
        return

    transitions = replay_memory_.sample(batch_size_)
    batch = Transition(*zip(*transitions))

    states = torch.stack(batch.state)
    actions = torch.stack(batch.action)
    rewards = torch.stack(batch.reward)
    next_states = torch.stack(batch.next_state)

    action_target = torch.argmax(actor_target(next_states.float()), 1).int()
    y = (
            rewards.float().view(-1, 1) +
            gamma_ * critic_target(next_states.float(), action_target.float())
            .float()
    )

    critic_trained.zero_grad()
    crit_ = critic_trained(states.float(), actions.float())
    # nn stuff does not work here! -> doing mse myself..
    # loss_critic = (torch.sum((y.float() - crit_.float()) ** 2.)
    #                / y.data.nelement())
    loss_critic = F.l1_loss(y.float(), crit_.float())
    loss_critic.backward()
    optimizer_critic.step()

    actor_trained.zero_grad()
    loss_actor = ((-1.) * critic_trained(states.float(),
                                         torch.argmax(
                                             actor_trained(states.float()), 1
                                         ).int().float())).mean()
    loss_actor.backward()
    optimizer_actor.step()


def get_eps(epoch):
    """
    Computes the eps for action choosing dependant on the epoch
    :param epoch: number of epoch
    :return:
    """
    if epoch <= 10:
        eps_ = 1.
    elif epoch <= 20:
        eps_ = 0.8
    elif epoch <= 40:
        eps_ = 0.6
    elif epoch <= 60:
        eps_ = 0.4
    elif epoch <= 80:
        eps_ = 0.2
    else:
        eps_ = 0.1
    return eps_


def compute_reward_2(state_, next_state_, terminal_state_):
    """
    Better (?) reward function that "compute_reward"
    If next_state == terminal_state -> reward = 100
    If next_state illegal           -> reward = -100
    if next_state is further away from terminal_state than state_ -> -2
    else 1
    :param state_:
    :param next_state_:
    :param terminal_state_:
    :return:
    """
    if torch.eq(next_state_, terminal_state_).all():
        reward_ = 100
    elif torch.eq(next_state_.abs(), 15).any():
        reward_ = -100
    else:
        if (state_.abs() > next_state_.abs()).any():
            reward_ = 1.
        else:
            reward_ = -2
    return torch.tensor(reward_, device=device, dtype=torch.float)


def compute_reward(next_state_, terminal_state_):
    """
    Computes some reward
    :param next_state_:
    :param terminal_state_:
    :return:
    """
    if torch.eq(next_state_, terminal_state_).all():
        return torch.tensor(100., device=device, dtype=torch.float)
    elif next_state_[0] == 15 or next_state_[1] == 15:
        return torch.tensor(-100., device=device, dtype=torch.float)
    else:
        return (-1.) * next_state_.abs().sum().float()


def fill_memory_2():
    """
    Fills the memory with random transitions which got a "good" action chosen
    """
    terminal_state_ = torch.tensor([0, 0], device=device, dtype=torch.int)
    while replay_memory_.__len__() < batch_size:
        state_ = torch.randint(-4, 4, (2,)).to(device).int()
        if state_[0].item() == 0 and state_[1].item == 0:
            continue

        # try to find a "good" action
        if state_[0].item() == 0:
            if state_[1].item() > 0:
                action_ = torch.tensor(1, device=device, dtype=torch.int)
            else:
                action_ = torch.tensor(0, device=device, dtype=torch.int)
        elif state_[1].item() == 0:
            if state_[0].item() > 0:
                action_ = torch.tensor(2, device=device, dtype=torch.int)
            else:
                action_ = torch.tensor(3, device=device, dtype=torch.int)
        else:
            random_bit = random.random()
            if random_bit > 0.5:
                if state_[1].item() > 0:
                    action_ = torch.tensor(1, device=device, dtype=torch.int)
                else:
                    action_ = torch.tensor(0, device=device, dtype=torch.int)
            else:
                if state_[0].item() > 0:
                    action_ = torch.tensor(2, device=device, dtype=torch.int)
                else:
                    action_ = torch.tensor(3, device=device, dtype=torch.int)

        action_ = action_.view(1).int()
        next_state_ = compute_next_state(action_, state_)
        reward_ = compute_reward_2(state_, next_state_, terminal_state_)

        transition__ = Transition(state=state_, action=action_,
                                  reward=reward_, next_state=next_state_)
        replay_memory_.push(*transition__)


def fill_memory():
    """
    Fills the memory with random transitions
    """
    while replay_memory_.__len__() < batch_size:
        state_ = torch.randint(-14, 15, (2,)).to(device).int()
        if state_[0].item() == 0 and state_[1].item == 0:
            continue
        terminal_state_ = torch.tensor([0, 0], device=device, dtype=torch.int)
        action_ = torch.randint(0, 4, (1,)).view(1).int()
        next_state_ = compute_next_state(action_, state_)
        reward_ = compute_reward_2(state_, next_state_, terminal_state_)

        transition__ = Transition(state=state_, action=action_,
                                  reward=reward_, next_state=next_state_)
        replay_memory_.push(*transition__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get device if possible
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    # set seed
    seed_ = 0
    random.seed(seed_)  # seed of python
    if device == "cuda":
        # cuda seed
        torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed_)
    else:
        # cpu seed
        torch.manual_seed(seed_)

    # initialize the nets
    actor_trained = actor().to(device)
    actor_target = actor().to(device)
    # copy -> _trained eqaul _target
    actor_target.load_state_dict(actor_trained.state_dict())
    optimizer_actor = optim.RMSprop(actor_trained.parameters())
    # move them to the device
    critic_trained = critic().to(device)
    critic_target = critic().to(device)
    critic_target.load_state_dict((critic_trained.state_dict()))
    actor_target.load_state_dict((actor_trained.state_dict()))
    # used optimizer
    optimizer_critic = optim.RMSprop(critic_trained.parameters(),
                                     momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.001)

    # replay memory
    capacity_replay_memory = 16384
    replay_memory_ = ReplayMemory(capacity_replay_memory)

    # hyperparams
    batch_size = 1024
    gamma = 0.7
    tau = 0.01
    num_epochs = 256

    # fill replay memory such that batching is possible
    fill_memory_2()

    # Print params
    printing_while_training = True
    printing_while_testing = False

    print('######################## Training ########################')
    starting_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range(num_epochs):
        # random state
        starting_state = torch.randint(-14, 15, (2,)).to(device).int()
        # skip if terminal state
        if starting_state[0].item() == 0 and starting_state[0].item() == 0:
            continue
        state = starting_state.clone()
        # terminal state
        terminal_state = torch.tensor([0, 0], device=device, dtype=torch.int)
        iteration = 0

        # get eps for exploring
        eps = get_eps(i)

        running_reward = 0.

        # training loos
        while True:
            # compute action and next state
            action = compute_action(actor_trained, state, eps)
            next_state = compute_next_state(action, state)

            # finished if next state is terminal state
            if torch.eq(next_state, terminal_state).all():
                reward = compute_reward_2(state, next_state, terminal_state)
                running_reward += reward.item()
                transition_ = Transition(state=state, action=action,
                                         reward=reward, next_state=next_state)
                replay_memory_.push(*transition_)
                if printing_while_training:
                    print('{}: Finished after {} iterations with reward {} '
                          'in state {} starting from {}'
                          .format(i + 1, iteration + 1, running_reward,
                                  next_state.data.numpy(),
                                  starting_state.data.numpy()))
                break
            # abort if illegal state
            elif torch.eq(next_state.abs(), 15).any() or iteration == 99:
                reward = compute_reward_2(state, next_state, terminal_state)
                running_reward += reward
                transition_ = Transition(state=state, action=action,
                                         reward=reward, next_state=next_state)
                replay_memory_.push(*transition_)
                if printing_while_training:
                    print('{}: Aborted after {} iterations with reward {} '
                          'in state {} starting from {}'
                          .format(i + 1, iteration + 1, running_reward,
                                  next_state.data.numpy(),
                                  starting_state.data.numpy()))
                break

            # compute immediate reward
            reward = compute_reward_2(state, next_state, terminal_state)
            # save it - only for logging purposes
            running_reward += reward.item()

            # construct transition
            transition_ = Transition(state=state, action=action, reward=reward,
                                     next_state=next_state)

            # update model
            update(transition_, replay_memory_, batch_size, gamma)
            # perform soft updates
            update_weights(actor_target, actor_trained, tau)
            update_weights(critic_target, critic_trained, tau)

            state = next_state
            iteration += 1
    print('Ended after: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now() - starting_time))

    print('######################## Testing ########################')
    starting_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    test_states = [torch.tensor([i, j], device=device, dtype=torch.int)
                   for i in range(-15, 14) for j in range(-15, 14)]
    finished = 0
    aborted = 0
    aborted_reward = []
    finished_reward = []

    for starting_state in test_states:
        state = starting_state.clone()
        terminal_state = torch.tensor([0, 0], device=device, dtype=torch.int)
        iteration = 0
        reward = 0.

        while True:
            action = torch.argmax(actor_target(state.float())).view(1).int()
            next_state = compute_next_state(action, state)

            if torch.eq(next_state, terminal_state).all():
                reward += compute_reward_2(state, next_state,
                                           terminal_state)
                finished_reward.append(reward.item())
                if printing_while_testing:
                    print('{}: Finished after {} iterations with reward {} '
                          'in state {} starting from {}'
                          .format(starting_state.data.numpy(), iteration + 1,
                                  reward.item(), next_state.data.numpy(),
                                  starting_state.data.numpy()))
                finished += 1
                break
            elif torch.eq(next_state.abs(), 15).any():
                reward += compute_reward_2(state, next_state,
                                           terminal_state)
                aborted_reward.append(reward.item())
                if printing_while_testing:
                    print('{}: Aborted after {} iterations with reward {} '
                          'in state {} starting from {}'
                          .format(starting_state.data.numpy(), iteration + 1,
                                  reward.item(), next_state.data.numpy(),
                                  starting_state.data.numpy()))
                aborted += 1
                break
            elif iteration > 500:
                if printing_while_testing:
                    print('Aborting due to more than 500 iterations! '
                          'Started from {}'.format(
                        starting_state.data.numpy()))
                aborted += 1
                break
            reward += compute_reward_2(state, next_state, terminal_state)
            state = next_state
            iteration += 1

    print('Ended after: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now() - starting_time))
    print('Finished: {}, aborted: {}'.format(finished, aborted))
    print('Reward mean finished: {}, aborted: {}'
          .format(np.mean(finished_reward), np.mean(aborted_reward)))
```

I already tried using an other reward function but it did not have any effect.. .

Additionally I tried using some less aggressive exploration and `optim.SGD` instead of `optim.RMSprop` - both had no effect.

Comment: how do you `nn.init` your weights?

Comment: Because the paper I read said, that the weights should be initialized uniformly, I  tried using `nn.init.uniform_` and `nn.init.xavier_uniform_`. Additionally I read, that if I do not initialize them manually, they will be set more or less randomly, so I tried using this (so no manual init) resulting in the same problem..

Comment: can you provide the full code to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the post.

Comment: I ran the test-block before and after training - the result was for both runs the same: (`Finished: 13, aborted: 828`,`Reward mean finished: 106.0, aborted: -115.39329268292683`). It seems like there is nothing learned..

Answer (score 2):

This might now be the direct answer or a recipe for your code to work, but I have some initial worries that might help you debug the code.

The biggest issue is, I believe, that you perform several conversions to datatypes that are not tensors. For example, you call your *combine_tensors()* functions couple of times, and it converts given tensors to *numpy()* and creates new tensor when returning the value. Other time you call your networks to perform the forward pass, and give them tensors converted with *float()* function as the argument. There are calls to *int()* on tensors aswell. All these calls cause losing the tensor's operation graph that is used for computing the gradient on the *backward()* call. This is described in PyTorch documentation and should be understood before writing RL algorithms in this framework. It is essential to work on the tensors for the whole time you are in the train function - from the time you convert the experience batch to tensors, to the time you call the backward functions.

This alone still does not guarantee that the learning will be performed in a correct way. For example, when you use the target networks to estimate the loss for critic, you should detach the results to prevent the gradient computations in target networks (although, if you use optimizer, and you register only the critic parameters, it is more of a performance issue as *step()* call won't update target network's parameters).

When both issues will be resolved in your code, you might observe more correct behaviour. My additional comment here is that I don't really understand parts of your code and I think it is not a correct DDPG implementation (i. e. you use *argmax()* on actor network output and provide this to critic network and this does not look like the correct way).

I'd advice you to take a step back and get a bit more understanding of PyTorch framework and ideas, as well as look for some baseline implementations of DDPG to make sure you know how to perform the calculations step by step.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. I already did what you have said (reading more about how to use PyTorch, RL, ...) and started implementing from scratch.. . Because there wasn't any interest in this question I did not update it but your comment is a good summary!